# How to test equality of an Array containing undefined elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, undefined

I encountered some weird behavior in the `assert` module of node.js. I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior.

When I create an array, and then initialize a value for example on the 3nd element, the first two elements are undefined. Testing whether the first two elements are undefined return true, however comparing the array as a whole with `undefined` for the first two elements fails.

```
var assert = require('assert');

var a = [];
a[2] = 2;
console.log(a);    // [ , , 2 ]

assert.equal(a[0], undefined);                  // ok
assert.equal(a[1], undefined);                  // ok
assert.equal(a[2], 2);                          // ok
assert.deepEqual(a, [, , 2]);                   // ok
assert.deepEqual(a, [undefined, undefined, 2]); // error ???
```

I can understand there is a difference between undefined elements and elements having a value `undefined`, as `Array` extends `Object`, and array elements are just properties on an object.

But why does the last assertion fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely because `[,,2]` and `[undefined,undefined,2]` don't have the same number of keys:

```
> Object.keys([,,2]).length
1
> Object.keys([undefined,undefined,2]).length
3
```

Here is the [relevant part](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/assert.js#L212-L222) of the `assert` code that is checking this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to step out on a limb here...

Most likely, `deepEqual` uses the `hasOwnProperty` method of object to make sure it doesn't catch any inherited properties.

If this is the case, the following console log may help you:

```
var test1 = [];
undefined

test1[2] = "xyzzy";
"xyzzy"

test1.hasOwnProperty(0)
false

test1.hasOwnProperty(1)
false

test1.hasOwnProperty(2)
true

var test2 = [undefined, undefined, "plugh"];
undefined

test2.hasOwnProperty(0)
true

test2.hasOwnProperty(1)
true

test2.hasOwnProperty(2)
true
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was thinking as well - that deepEqual loops over all properties. Paul Mougel answer confirms it is related to properties but assert actually counts the number of properties (keys).

Comment: Yup, I saw that.  His answer was *much* more specific than mine so full props to him.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess. It appears that there is a distinction between array locations that contain nothing (i.e., uninitialized) and are `undefined`, versus actually sticking an actual `undefined` into a specific location in an array.

You can actually see this in Chrome on the console log:

```
> a = [undefined, undefined, 2];
  [undefined, undefined, 2]

> b = [,,2]
  [undefined × 2, 2]

> c = [];
> c[2] = 2;
> c
  [undefined × 2, 2]
```

It's a very subtle difference; in the first case ([,,2]) you created an array without anything in locations `0` and `1`; it's a spare array where only location `3` contains a value. In the second case, you created an array which *isn't* a spare array. Instead you specifically inserted the value `undefined` at locations `1` and `2`. It appears that both these cases are treated differently which is probably why they are not equal.

I think it might be easier to visualize the first array as `[,,2] = [uninitialized, uninitialized, 2]`. So the distinction is between an *uninitialized* value versus a concrete *undefined* that has been inserted into the array (which means the location is not uninitialized).

**UPDATE**

I took a look [at the code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/assert.js#L221-L222) in `assert.js`. Specifically, pay attention to lines 221 and 222:

```
 if (ka.length != kb.length)
    return false;
```

`ka` and `kb` are set in lines 213-215:

```
 var ka = Object.keys(a),
        kb = Object.keys(b),
        key, i;
```

The value of `Object.keys(a).length` for `[,,2]` is `1` whereas the value of `Object.keys(b).length` for `[undefined, undefined, 2]` is `3`. This is why they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug. Those arrays have different behaviour. Consider the following use case:

```
function log(item, idx) {
    console.log(item, " - ", idx);
}

a.map(log); // 2 - 2

[undefined, undefined, 2].map(log); //undefined - 0 undefined - 0 2 - 2
```